# How does a rectilinear filter used for QKD-BB84 detect both horizontal and vertical polarizations?

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography

When using the BB84 algorithm for QKD, you arbitrarily choose which of two filters (bases) to use when detecting a photon:  rectilinear or diagonal.  If you choose rectilinear, you can detect polarization with certainty if the photon is rectilinear, i.e., either vertically- or horizontally-polarized.

1. But how?  A polarization filter that allows transmission of
   vertically-polarized photons will block horizontally-polarized
   photons and vice-versa, no?
2. Perhaps you use a
   vertically-polarized filter as the rectilinear filter and then the
   complete lack of a photon indicates horizontal polarization, but how
   would you distinguish that from, say, absorption of the photon into
   the fiber?

Comment: This may be better to be asked Quantum.Se site or Physics.SE?

Comment: Perhaps--it really is a physics question.